# While I use ampersent '&' inside sql query delete it ignores after text ! and query gets false

Tags: php, html, mysql

I write this query in PHP.

Example

```
$name='MIKE & JOHN';
$query = "DELETE * FROM `user` WHERE `name` = '$name'";
```

When it actually executes it shows like below...

```
echo"$query";
```

Output:-

```
DELETE * FROM `user` WHERE `name`= 'MIKE';
```

As the output shows after MIKE, they ignored the whole sentence. 
Now how to solve this problem?

Pls, help guys thanks in advance.

Comment: Yet another problem you wouldn't have with [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712037/what-is-parameterized-query) so now's probably the right moment to learn about them and consequently start using them everywhere. As a bonus, you won't have any problems with sql injection anymore.

Comment: `DELETE *` is a nonsensical construction

Comment: I would recomend to look up the [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php)

Answer (score 0):

I try it and this ok
`` DELETE * FROM `user` WHERE `name` = 'MIKE & JOHN'[Finished in 0.2s] ``
if you trying send $name result via http GET link check it var_dump($_GET), http split it.

Comment: Yes Bro, I am using $_GET to pass the parameters. Please elaborate how to send '&' ampersand with GET method.